# Finding denominators of Farey tree fractions in constant time

Tags: r

Hello [r](/questions/tagged/r) masters.

I need to calculate Denominators of Farey tree fractions up to 2**30.

I came up with this C++ solution using [this approach](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fractions/fareySB.html):

```
struct FareySB {
    int num, den;

    FareySB() : den(0) {}

    int sum() {
        return num + den;
    }
};

const int LGMAX = 30;
const int MAX = 1 << LGMAX;
FareySB FTF[MAX];

void get_FTF() {
    FTF[0].num = 0; FTF[0].den = 1;
    FTF[1].num = 1; FTF[1].den = 1;
    FTF[2].num = 1; FTF[2].den = 2;

    int k = 3;
    for (int i = 1; i < LGMAX; i++) {
        int len = 1 << i;
        int hlen = len >> 1;

        for (int j=0; j<hlen; j++) {
            FTF[k].num = FTF[k-hlen].num;
            FTF[k].den = FTF[k-hlen].sum();
            k++;
        }
        for (int j=0; j<hlen; j++) {
            FTF[k].num = FTF[k-len].den;
            FTF[k].den = FTF[k-1-(j<<1)].den;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

To know the n-th term I need to know all [0..n-1] terms. Ok so far.

This has a problem: memory just explodes after about 2**27.

---

The denominators of Farey Tree Fractions are the [OEIS-A007306](https://oeis.org/A007306):

> 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7, ...

In that OEIS page I found a code which seems to return the n-th term of the sequence in constant time. If thats true it would solve my Memory Limit Exceeded issue.

But the code is in R language:

```
(R)
# Given n, compute directly a(n)
# by taking into account the binary representation of n-1
aa <- function(n){
  b <- as.numeric(intToBits(n))
  l <- sum(b)
  m <- which(b == 1)-1
  d <- 1
  if(l > 1) for(j in 1:(l-1)) d[j] <- m[j+1]-m[j]+1
  f <- c(1, m[1]+2) # In A002487: f <- c(0, 1)
  if(l > 1) for(j in 3:(l+1)) f[j] <- d[j-2]*f[j-1]-f[j-2]
  return(f[l+1])
}
# a(0) = 1, a(1) = 1, a(n) = aa(n-1)   n > 1
```

It may be really simple to you, but I don't know R language, and can't understand the above code.

Is it really a constant function? How does that function works?

If you could show me for a given `n` whats happening inside this function, then I could be able to code it in C++ myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure quite how it works, but here is what the R code is doing. Assume `n=100`.

`b <- as.numeric(intToBits(n))` this produces a 32-element vector of a (reversed) binary representation of `n`.  For `n=100`, `b` is `0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

`l <- sum(b)` is the sum of the elements of `b` (i.e. the number of 1s).  In this case `l=3`

`m <- which(b == 1)-1` is a vector of the indices of the elements of `b` that are equal to 1, each reduced by 1.  So for `n=100`, `m= 2 5 6`

`d <- 1` just setting `d` equal to `1`

`if(l > 1) for(j in 1:(l-1)) d[j] <- m[j+1]-m[j]+1`. If `l` is bigger than one, then `d` becomes a vector of length `l-1`, where each `d` is the differences between successive values of `m`, plus one.  So for `n=100`, `d= 4 2`

`f <- c(1, m[1]+2)` sets `f` as a vector with the first value `1`, second value the first element of `m`, plus 2.  Here `f` is `1 4`

`if(l > 1) for(j in 3:(l+1)) f[j] <- d[j-2]*f[j-1]-f[j-2]`. If `l` is bigger than one, this adds elements onto the end of `f`, according to that formula - e.g. `f[3]` is `d[1]*f[2]-f[1]` or `4*4-1=15`. For `n=100`, `f` is `1 4 15 26`.

`return(f[l+1])` This returns the last element of `f` as the result.

I'm not sure whether it is constant, but it looks pretty quick as `n` increases.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will code it in C++ right now